# Why doesn't the undo/redo panel appear when I start a shake gesture in iPhone Simulator?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I've created an NSUndoManager for the Managed Object Context of Core Data, like this:

```
NSUndoManager *undoManager = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];
[undoManager setLevelsOfUndo:10];
[managedObjectContext setUndoManager:undoManager];
[undoManager release];
```

In the app delegate where the didFinishLaunching method is called, I did this:

```
application.applicationSupportsShakeToEdit = YES;
```

For some reason, I never get that undo/redo panel when I make a shake gesture in iPhone Simulator (from the menu). Must I enable undo/redo somewhere else, maybe in the Info.plist file?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449268/how-does-undo-redo-basically-work-on-iphone-os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lukya pointed out, you already asked this question back in March.