# How would I implement undo in an OpenGL ES painting application on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm using Apple's sample application GLPaint as a basis for an OpenGL ES painting application, but I can't figure out how to implement undo functionality within it.

I don't want to take images of every stroke and store them.  Is there any way of using different frame buffer objects to implement undo?  Do you have other suggestions for better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 10):

Use vertex buffer objects (VBO) to render your content. On every new stroke copy the last VBO to some least recently used (LRU) list. If your LRU is full, delete the least recently used VBO. To restore (undo) the last stroke just use the most recently used VBO of the LRU and render it.

VBO:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html

LRU:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used

Comment: Could you please provide some sample code on how to implement this?

Comment: Shake to undo :-) Does this work for you? https://github.com/larsxschneider/Undo-in-OpenGL-ES

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much! I will be in touch to show you what I did with it. Bounty well deserved.

Comment: @antalkerekes I am interested and I am looking forward to it :-)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work at all.
Comparing with the original code of GLPaint, it really didn't undo all in once. But the undo is not working as expected. It doesn't undo the last action and the color changed wrong after undo.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to render all the previous vertex buffer objects in order for this to look right?

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend using NSUndoManager to store a list of the actual drawing actions undertaken by the user (draw line from here to here using this paintbrush, etc.).  If stored as a list of x, y coordinates for vector drawing, along with all other metadata required to recreate that part of the drawing, you won't be using anywhere near as much memory as storing images, vertex buffer objects, or framebuffer objects.

In fact, if you store these drawing steps in a Core Data database, you can almost get undo / redo for free.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449268/how-does-undo-redo-basically-work-on-iphone-os/2450139#2450139) for more.

Comment: Saving all the steps and then redrawing them -last step (undo) can get very slow when you have many steps to redraw, am i missing something?

Comment: I would suggest storing a raw image every 10 or so check points so you don't have to redraw the last 100 steps or something crazy

Answer (score 1):

To undo in a graphical application, you can use coreData.

[here is a detailed blogpost](http://www.ioslearner.com/undo-redo-support-core-data-nsundomanager/) and [read this one](http://www.mikeabdullah.net/core_data_undo_management.html) as well.

Answer (score -1):

Either you can use NSUndoManager, class provided by iOS

Or you can save current state of screen area by:

```
CGContextRef current = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

You can have one array as stack with screen image objects and on undo action you can pop value from stack and on each change push value into the stack.

Comment: The asker is looking for a solution involving OpenGL ES, and graphics states as you describe only work for Core Graphics. They would not apply here.