# undo redo in opengl in iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am implementing undo redo in opengl on apple GLPaint Code. Currently my approach is that:

1. Clear all buffer.
2. Redraw all data again except last one.

But this makes performance issue.  Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

solution
https://github.com/larsxschneider/Undo-in-OpenGL-ES

discussion 
[How would I implement undo in an OpenGL ES painting application on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474252/how-would-i-implement-undo-in-an-opengl-es-painting-application-on-the-iphone)

and you can easy add redo.

Comment: https://github.com/larsxschneider/Undo-in-OpenGL-ES,  This uses the same approach as I an using.Each time it draws whole drawing again and again.This is not good performance wise if I use very larger texture.

Comment: y, you right, I rewrote this solution. In my solution drawing with lines.(sorry can't share it)

Comment: But if you can give some idea for this.You need not to share your whole code.Your support will be appreciable.