# iPhone redo a pressed button in apple manner

Tags: iphone, copy-paste, undo-redo

As iPhone has a copy past feature for text, with a nice redo handler by shaking the phone, Im wondering whether I can use this feature to redo a button touch action who was touched mistakenly by the user.

Any idea?

Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.  In short, you will want to use NSUndoManager or Core Data's undo capabilities to manage this.

For a more detailed description of this process, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449268/how-does-undo-redo-basically-work-on-iphone-os/2450139#2450139).