# Help with NSUndoManager

Tags: iphone, undo, foundation, nsundomanager

Ok, So i want to add the ability to undo certain actions in my app.  I was going to create a way to do it, with my own protocals or something, but then I found out about `NSUndoManager`.  I would like to use the built in foundation way, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I need to undo multiple dice rolling, so if I could store the previous rolls, as objects in an `NSArray`, would probably be the best.  I could use an `NSMutableString`, but the array would be preferred.

Then I know you can shake to undo, but I would rather have a button.  These has been giving me  the most trouble.  I've included my attempts below.  None of those have worked.  Any help would be appreciated.

In viewDidLoad:

```
undoManager = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];
```

Then in the method that rolls the dice, I tried:

```
   [[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] undoButton];
    [[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] 
    [[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", dice1num]];

setStrings:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", dice1num]
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", dice1num],
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", dice1num],
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", dice1num],
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", dice1num], nil]];
[[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:@selector()];
[undoManager setActionName:@"A roll"];
```

And then here is the IBAction that links to the undo button:

```
-(IBAction)undoButton{
           [undoManager undo];
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: My answer to this question might also be helpful here: [How does undo/redo basically work on iPhone OS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449268/how-does-undo-redo-basically-work-on-iphone-os)

Comment: Brad, I skimmed your answer and it looks really good.  I wish I had seem that a few days ago.  I'll probably take a few things away from that.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Apple's DotViewUndo sample code helped me get up and running. It's a tiny little project gathering dust here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/DotViewUndo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008851-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have gotten the function of the `NSUndoManager` wrong. An undo manager is like a stack of invocations which are needed to reverse the thing you just did. So in principle your idea is right to use a collection object in your case an `NSArray` to store multiple undo steps. Unfortunately it works a litte bit different.

### How `NSUndoManager` works

An undo manager works by maintaining a stack of undo steps in memory. For each step in your case dice roll you want to undo you register an invocation object using the `- (void)registerUndoWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setMyObjectTitle:) object:currentTitle` method. You do this for every dice roll. Do only register one operation at a time.

For undoing you call the undo method as you did and what happens then is that the undo manager pops an operation of the undo stack and executes it.

*Your main mistake was to try to reinvent how the undo manager works. Do not register an array, just use one dice roll at a time.*

[Apple's undo architecture manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/UndoArchitecture.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000010i)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I had to do a little playing around and modify the concept to fit my needs but I got it.  Thanks again