# Show "Done" navigation item on UIKeyboardWillShowNotification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, user-interface, uinavigationbar

I have a UINavigationBar that has two button items already. I will need to allow a textview to fill up the space between the nav bar and keyboard, so the only option is a "done item" on the right-hand side of nav-bar.

The question: What do I do with the buttons I already have, how should a transition occur (with animation or not?). Should I create a new navigationbar so I can revert back to the current one, or swap out the title, and buttons (storing them in buffer till I need it later) of the existing one.

As a bonus question: If I wanted to have a cancel (or maybe revert) button on the left, is there a no-effort way of reverting in UITextView, or should I just store the NSString* in a buffer.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always create a separate toolbar below, and animate it on.
Or, you could use [inputAccessoryView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) to assign a toolbar to with those buttons on.

As to your bonus questions,
there is system-wide undo in iOS 3 (I think) +. You might want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2449268/840973) question

Comment: That's some great information. I think I'll go with the toolbar option, because I don't think iPhone is allowed to show the keyboard dismissal button.